# Can't over-ride certain css objects theme in the .dialog() widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I'm having trouble with overriding the css theme with the `.dialog()` box. I followed instructions here http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#theming and I am not able to resolve this issue.  I am using the `dialogClass` option with the `.dialog()` widget so it should append the styles I apply to them, like this:

Javascript Initialization:

```
$("#modal").dialog({
   dialogClass: "css" 
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="modal"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.css .ui-dialog-content { 
    border:1px solid #ddd; 
    background-color:#333; 
    padding:50px !important; }
```

Ok so the documentation says I can style the `.ui-dialog-content` class and the objects, and it works, SOMEWHAT. The border and background-color works, but the padding doesn't work because it's styled in the `element.style` and even using `!important` doesn't over-ride it, so it's basically not letting me change any pre-existing settings to the modal classes, even when using `!important`, I am wondering if anyone knows how to get this to work, starting with getting the `padding` to work on the `.ui-dialog-content` class.

You can see a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tsy52/

Comment: padding seems to be working perfectly fine..

Comment: Not here, try removing it and seeing if the size actually changes.

Comment: The content has no initial padding property. So setting it works even without using `!important`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take `min-height` for example.

It has a inline style of `min-height:28px`

If you want to change that adding `CSS` to that class will not help as the specificity for inline styles is greater than that of `CSS`

The order goes this way

```
!important > inline styles > class property
```

Using `!important` is a bad pattern and has to be avoided. In such cases you would set the `CSS` property on the element directly.

```
$('.ui-dialog-content').css("min-height", "100px")
```

After the dialog is initialized.